# Java incorrect incompatible types exception when Supplier returns generic Optional

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I have written the following helper method which I think is self explanatory:

```
protected <T> Optional<T> handleErrors(Supplier<Optional<T>> supplier, String fieldName) {
    try {
        return supplier.get();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        errors.add(ParseError.builder()
                .message(e.getMessage())
                .field(fieldName)
                .exception(e)
                .build());

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

When I use this method and try to use use Lambda reference like below, I get an error saying:
 `incompatible types: invalid method reference`

This throws the exception during compilation:

```
handleErrors(() -> getField(unit, "price"), "price.amount")
        .ifPresent(builder::price);
```

These following cases works but IntelliJ displays a warning:

```
handleErrors(() -> getField(unit, "price"), "price.amount")
        .ifPresent(price -> builder.price(price));
```

```
Optional<String> price = handleErrors(() -> getField(unit, "price"), "price.amount");
price.ifPresent(builder::price);
```

Why does it throw an exception when I use Lambda reference directly on the returned Optional and

Comment: What warnings and errors did IntelliJ display?

Comment: "Lambda can be replaced with method reference", which throws an incompatible types exception if I change it.

Comment: What is the signatures of `getField` and `builder::price`?

Comment: Does `builder.price(price)` return anything? Could it be that `builder::price` doesn't conform to `Consumer<T>` which is the type `ifPresent` expects?

Comment: "throws the exception during compilation" Exceptions are not thrown during compilation. What do you mean?